# How to get value out of promise when used along with async/await?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to run a parallel async function call using async/await and I am not sure how to recover the returned object from the async call.

```
async function doit(){
  const meta = call1;   // async call 1
  const data = call2;   // async call 2
  await meta;
  await data;
  console.log(meta);
```

The output is

```
Promise { Returned value }
```

So how do I get the *Returned value* from the async call?

Edit: I was trying out the example from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions). Check the "Careful! Avoid going too sequential part".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the return values, I'd use something like the following:

```
async function doit(){
  // create all async requests
  const metaReq = call1();   // async call 1
  const dataReq = call2();   // async call 2

  // wait for them
  const [meta, data] = await Promise.all( [ metaReq, dataReq ] );

  // use them
  console.log(meta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions needs to return a `Promise`.

```
'use strict';

async function doit() {

  let [meta,data] = await Promise.all([call1(),call2()]);

  console.log(meta);
}
```

Comment: This will create a sequential flow. I was trying out a parallel flow as described here. Check "Careful! Avoid going too sequential" part. Any thoughts?

Comment: @James Are you wrapping the return values from call1() and call2()? Can you please post the function?